# JavaScript String.replace()

Tags: javascript, regex, string

The following replacement

```
"index.html".replace('\.html$', '_fr.html');
```

returns "index.html", indicating that the first argument didn't match anything. However, if I remove the "$"

```
"index.html".replace('\.html', '_fr.html');
```

then the first argument matches and "index_fr.html" is returned.

Returning to the first example, can someone explain why ".html$" does not seem to match "index.html"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's not a regular expression - regex literals in JavaScript look like:

```
/\.html$/
```

without quotes. String.replace takes a string or a regular expression literal.